# Spring Data JPA detached entity back to context

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have `Person` entity with lazily fetched `List<Contact> contacts`.

I got my `person` entity object and some time later I want to get person's contacts (obviously I can do that only if entity is managed).

What is the best way to merge/put to context `person` entity in Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers my question:

```
Person managedPerson = personRepository.save(person)
```

`save` method checks if `person` entity is new. If it is so, it persists entity, otherwise it merges it and returns back managed entity